# Checkout all submodules from bare repo?

Tags: git, version-control, git-submodules, git-checkout, git-bare

When I checkout the master branch of my bare repo using

```
git --work-tree=/path/to/destination --git-dir=/path/to/bare/repo checkout -f
```

It checks out the entire working branch, but not the contents of the submodules, only the parent directory of those submodules.  How can I checkout every submodule to the destination folder?

Comment: The command can also checkout submodules to destination. Did you commit and push the submodules into the bare repo?

Comment: Has your problem been solved yet?

Answer (score 1):

```
git submodule sync --recursive
git submodule update --recursive
```